# Does all mobile browsers on Android, iOS and WP7+8 send HTTP referer?

Tags: android, ios, http, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm wondering if requiring the HTTP referer being the current domain would be a working solution for a mobile specific web site.

The arguments for using antixss tokens has traditionally been that HTTP referer is sometimes turned off by security applications. However, I have a feeling that with mobile browsers it's probably not something that happens.